# How can I get images to fit inside table cell in html?

Tags: html

I have given the cell a height and width of 100 but the images are still coming out full size instead of resizing to fit inside the cell. How can I fix this?
Here is my code

```
<table style="width:100%; text-align:center">
<tr>
<td style="width: 100; height:100"><img src="images/c-plus-plus-logopng- 
c-plus-plus-png-500_500.png"/></td>
<td style="width: 100; height:100"><img src="images/c-plus-plus-logopng- 
c-plus-plus-png-500_500.png"/></td>
<td style="width: 100; height:100"><img src="images/c-plus-plus-logopng- 
c-plus-plus-png-500_500.png"/></td>
<td style="width: 100; height:100"><img src="images/c-plus-plus-logopng- 
c-plus-plus-png-500_500.png"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100; height:100"><img src="images/c-plus-plus-logopng-c- plus-plus-png-500_500.png"/></td>
<td style="width: 100; height:100"><img src="images/c-plus-plus-logopng-c-plus-plus-png-500_500.png"/></td>
<td style="width: 100; height:100"><img src="images/c-plus-plus-logopng-c-plus-plus-png-500_500.png"/></td>
<td style="width: 100; height:100"><img src="images/c-plus-plus-logopng-c-plus-plus-png-500_500.png"/></td>
</tr>
 
</table>
```

Comment: `width: 100;` isn't valid CSS. Use `width: 100px;` or `width: 100%;`

Comment: `width: 100;` is not a valid value. You are missing the unit (e.g. `px`). But besides that if you want to serve images at a specific size then you should just create them at that size to save bandwidth for the user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `width: 100;` isn't valid CSS. Use `width: 100px;` or `width: 100%;`

---

That said, to contain and center images inside a `<td>`, use the image as a `background-image`, then add a `width` + `height` to the `<td/>`

```css
td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; text-align:center">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/500x500');" /></td>
        <td style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/500x500');" /></td>
        <td style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/500x500');" /></td>
        <td style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/500x500');" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/500x500');" /></td>
        <td style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/500x500');" /></td>
        <td style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/500x500');" /></td>
        <td style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/500x500');" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Note;** I've replaced your images for some placeholders.